# Ungrammatical or Grammatically Incorrect

Tags: terminology, grammaticality

When I asked which of "ungrammatical" or "grammatically incorrect" is prefered and why? at an English language forum I got the following "linguistic perspective":

> Both are used, but I believe linguists prefer the former. Grammaticality, as one linguist explained it to me, means "following the rules of the relevant scientific model that is used to describe how people speak". So it is strictly dependent on the model used, but in practice many linguists presume that there is consensus about most elements of the relevant model, so it mostly overlaps with "people actually use this within a certain group and they consider it normal".
>
> The word "incorrect" may suggest that there is something wrong with straying from grammatically; I suspect that linguists do not use this much because they resent the implication. So I think that's why you will mostly see ungrammatical.

Could you please comment on the linguistic accuracy of this answer?

Comment: I am not a syntactician, so I don't feel comfortable giving a full answer but in my department we tend to talk about things be "grammatical" or "not grammatical" with the implication being that it's short for "not grammatical in my dialect". The reason is that the alternatives you give imply a right way and a wrong way when in linguistics it's more about attested/unattested. What's "ungrammatical" in one dialect may very well be grammatical in another. Of course, in casual conversation the two options you give are essentially the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes linguists, as describers rather than prescribers, still have a need to distinguish between grammatical and not but don't have a need to distinguish between correct and not.

Comment: I'm not exactly a linguist, but I see no difference between *ungrammatical* and *grammatically incorrect*. I can't imagine a sentence that is one, but not the other.

Comment: I agree with the quote.

Comment: @prash. Language mavens would say split infinitives or dangling participles are either "ungrammatical" or "grammatically" incorrect. But linguists would say they are "grammatical" because speakers use them all the time and listeners always comprehend. Linguists would not enter into making a judgement about whether those constructions are "correct". Linguists would say "I ain't got no money" is "grammatical" and "I aren't haves no moneys" is "ungrammatical" because our shared language rules permit the former and not the latter.

Comment: @hippietrail: The rule against split infinitives may have come about because people wanted English to be more like Latin. I have met a few language mavens, but none of them say anything against split infinitives. "I ain't got no money" brings us to the issue of dialects and registers. We all agree that "I aren't haves no moneys" is ungrammatical. I'll ask a few linguists if they'd say it is "grammatically incorrect" too.

Comment: Whenever I see somebody asking about "correct" on any linguistic forum, I itch to reply "Tell us which authority you want to follow and we can tell you whether it is correct". There are no authorities for English, and so nobody able to rule on "correct". "Grammatical" and "ungrammatical", as used by linguists, mean "what a native speaker would/wouldn't produce or accept".

Comment: @ColinFine: This sentence have speling and gramar error's, me could of "corrected" them. My point is that there are many kinds of errors, and so, there are many levels on which something could be "correct" or "incorrect". Not all of it requires authorities to define rules for correctness.

Comment: Wait just a minute here. In English, "Thanks God" is ungrammatical or grammatically incorrect, regardless of the variety you speak. And: "I'm going to school now" is incorrect in AAVE, where it should be: *I be going* to school now. At an interview for a law practice, you wouldn't want to say: He *don't* speak Chinese. So, it does not depend  on the "model"; it depends on the variety (yeah, dialect) of English used as a baseline. Non-linguists have a hard time this.